# Random number and switch statement

Tags: c#, random, switch-statement

```
if (((turn % 2) != 0) && (vsComputer))
    {
        int generateAI = generateRandomAI(AI);
        switch (generateAI)
            {
                 case 0:                            
                 computerMedio();
                 break;

                 case 1:
                 computerDifficile();
                 break;
             }
}
```

I want my 0/1 value to be the same for all the game.
With the code I wrote, on every move it selects a different AI mode.

It shouldn't be that hard to achieve, but I can't find a solution.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just generate a random number once, at the start of the game, instead of generating a new random number on each computer turn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved in the following way

```
public Boolean difficult;
```

in the newGame() method I generate the number which lasts for all the game.
then,

```
switch (generateAI)
    {
         case 0:                            
         difficult = false;
         break;

         case 1:
         difficult = true;
         break;
    }
```

into the game:

```
 if (((turn % 2) != 0) && (vsComputer))
     {
          if (difficult)
          {
               computerDifficile();
          }
          else
          {
               computerMedio();
          }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is:

```
int generateAI = generateRandomAI(AI);
```

You are generating a new random value on every invocation of this code block.  If you wish to keep the same value for all execution, just generate the value once and keep it in scope.